# C++ - set base class vptr without constructor?

Tags: c++, base-class, vptr

I've written a memory manager in C++. The details aren't important, but when set up it allocates a large byte array from the heap, and when its allocate function is called, it clears some free memory bytes to 0 and returns a pointer to them. So an example of use would be:

```
memoryManager->initialise(1024); //Allocates 1024 bytes
T* t = memoryManager->allocate<T>(); //Prepares sizeof(T) bytes and returns a ptr
```

This works great, I've thoroughly tested it and it works exactly as intended. However, since it just makes a "fake" pointer, the object's constructor doesn't get called. This falls apart when I try to allocate a class that inherits from another - its vptr never gets set, since that's done at the start of the constructor and hidden from the programmer. So as soon as I call a base class function, the program crashes with a seg fault.

Is there any way around this? Can I set it myself?

**Edit: to anyone else looking for a way to do this, do a search for "placement new". Read comments for more info.**

Comment: Search for "placement new"

Comment: You're going to find the syntax `new(memptr) type( args) ;`  calls the constructor in place on the memory you created for it.  Also look at the implementation of things like `vector::emplace_back`

Comment: @woolstar Thanks, that's perfect. I'll edit it into the question since no one has posted an answer.